# Phalcon "use Vendor\Package" pass to view

Tags: php, phalcon

I'm a website developer currently using Laravel as my main Framework for work. I would like to get into using Phalcon for any projects which may benefit from it, but having trouble getting my head around some thing.

I would like to know know how to add a use Vendor\Package into a controller which then gets passed over to the view?

Currently, the documentation shows that the 'use' case is being added into the view which is something I don't want as I like to have my views tidy and believe this should be done in the controller.

I've currently tried...

```
<?php

use Phalcon\Tag;

class IndexController extends ControllerBase {

    public function indexAction()
    {

    }

}
```

And then in my view added...

```
<h2>Sign up using the form below</h2>

<?php echo Tag::form("signup/register"); ?>

<p>
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <?php echo Tag::textfield("name") ?>
</p>

<p>
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <?php echo Tag::textfield("username") ?>
</p>

<p>
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <?php echo Tag::passwordField("password") ?>
</p>

<p>
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <?php echo Tag::textfield("email") ?>
</p>

<p>
    <?php echo Tag::submitButton("Register") ?>
</p>
```

But then it says that the class Tag can not be found. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not using it as in [docs](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/tags.html#tag-service)?

Besides that I don't think PHP work the way you want.

You are using `use` statement in one file and you expect to work in other.

According to docs the easiest way to do it is to:

```
<?php echo $this->tag->textfield("email") ?>
```

SInce this is a `tag` service and you have access to it on view instance (so while rendering a view).

Comment: Thank you, I have added the use in my controller and passed each field as a variable so $this->view->form = Tag::form("signup/register"); gets passed to my view and I can do {{ view.form }} which works nicely.